# Setting a shell variable in a null coalescing fashion

Tags: bash, shell, variable

I'm really fond of "null coalescing", where you can set a variable to the first "non-null" value in a list of things. Many languages support this, for example:

**C#:**

```
String myStr = string1 ?? string2 ?? "default";
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var myStr = string1 || string2 || "default";
```

...etc. I'm just curious if this can be done in Bash to set a variable?

**pseudo:**

```
MY_STR=$ENV{VAR_NAME}??$ANOTHER_VAR??"default";
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The POSIX shell (so includes `bash`) equivalent would be:

```
${FOO:-${BAR:-default}}
```

See also the:

```
${FOO-${BAR-default}}
```

variant which checks whether the variable is set or not instead of whether it resolves to the empty string or not (which makes a difference in the cases where a variable is set but empty).

Answer (score 13):

Not directly.

```
my_str="${var_name:-${another_var:-default}}"
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to official documentation?