bash 5.2.x + ternary operator: How can I use this combo when checking if my string variable is empty or not?
I have tried
#!/bin/bash

distro=""

myvar1=[[ -n "$distro" ]] && echo $distro || echo "debian"
myvar2=$((-n $distro ? $distro : "debian"))

these are the results of the script
./build.sh: line 5: -n: command not found
debian
./build.sh: line 6: -n  ?  : debian: expression expected (error token is ": debian")


This question is similar to: Setting a shell variable in a null coalescing fashion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@muru I tried the suggestions there and all I get is "=debian: comman not found"

You tried https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62336/70524 and got that error?

To be frank, both of the assignments there look like things mashed up almost randomly. [[ .. ]] returns the truth value in the exit status, so you can't use it in an assignment like that. (Though myvar1=$([[ -n "$distro" ]] && echo $distro || echo "debian") might work.) myvar1=[[ -n is similar to foo=bar somecmd, i.e. an assignment with a command. And $(( .. )) is an arithmetic expansion, it doesn't have -n in that sense. -n is a unary minus and the variable n. You get the syntax error because there's nothing between ? and :.

As always, A && B || C is not a proper ternary operator as it runs C if A is false or if B is false. That should really go out of your vocabulary.
You want:
if A; then
  B
else
  C
fi

Or if A; then B; else C; fi if you need it on one line.
In your case:
if [ -n "$distro" ]; then
  myvar=$distro
else
  myvar=debian
fi

There is a ternary operator in the C-style arithmetic expressions, but that's for arithmetic only, so only works for numbers (in the case of bash, that's even limited to decimal integer numbers).
You can do:
(( myvar =  ${#distro} ? 12 : 42 ))

But not assign strings to myvar.
Here though, there are dedicated operators from the Bourne shell (from the late 70s) for that very purpose:
myvar=${distro:-debian}

Where ${distro:-debian} expands to debian if $distro is unset or empty.
Or
: "${distro:=debian}"

Where ${distro:=debian} works like ${distro:-debian} and also assigns debian to $distro if $distro was unset or empty. Note the need for quotes around the expansion as it's now a list context.
Note the variants without : for unset only instead of unset or empty.

integers, yes, but not just decimals in that it supports arbitrary bases (up to base 64(!)) with 16#1f and the like, though the results end up in decimal anyway.

@ilkkachu, the point is that in bash contrary to zsh, you can't have expansions in bases other than 10, and can't assign non-decimal integers to variable. In zsh, you can do var=$(( [##36] 36#debian )) or (( [##36] var = 36#debian )) which will assign DEBIAN to $var.
